# Visit pages based on User Type

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have built my load test Jmeter script and it looks good. Now there is one addition I want to add here which  might need some condition but I am not sure what is best way to achieve that.

I have 2 user types :

1. Free
2. Paid

Currently load test script is fine with free users. Taking login details from CSV and visit pages and all good.

Now there are few special pages which are only accessible to paid users. I am not sure how to set condition in Jmeter like if user is paid then visit page X else skip it.

All users are in same CSV files. (I can add separate CSV for paid users if needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how these free/paid users can be distinguished the options are in:

1. If you have `${paid}` variable which can be `true` or `false` you could use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with the relevant condition and put the [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) specific for the paid users under it

   [image]

   this way only if `${paid}` variable is `true` the If Controller's children will be executed:

   [image]
2. if you have a variable which can be either `free` or `paid` another option is using [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) like:

   [image]

   so Switch Controller's children will be executed depending on the `${paid}` variable value:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for both options. So For the switch will it automatically consider free if variable is not paid?

And for this can I do like add one more column in CSV called usertype and provide free and paid and use that as variable?

Comment: If the variable doesn't match any of the Switch Controller's children - the first option will be executed